# How to connect laptop hdd to desktop?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive

I found a latop hdd other day in the house. I will probably get rid of it, but first I want to have a look at what is in it, because I think it has some documents and codes from my previous work.

How can I connect laptop hdd to desktop PC?

Thinking that this will be a one time operation cheap option is more likely to be selected than expensive & reliable option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this before and it comes in quite handy.

http://sabrent.com/v2/usb-2-0-to-idesata-2-53-55-25-hard-drive-converter-with-power-supply-led-activity-lights-2/

Comment: I liked the way it can be used for lots of devices.

Comment: Yeah, I've used it a bunch of times. Money well spent.